Does VS C++ compiler handle 80-bit floating point numbers, or long double?
I need to read an 80-bit floating point number from memory and format it to the user (in a human-readable decimal form) in a string buffer. I tried long double and VS C++ compiler seems to treat it just as a plain (64-bit)  single-precisiondouble.
Is there a way to have VS C++ work with 80-bit double-precision floating point numbers?
And if so, how to sprintf them, or with which % specifier?

The rule in C and C++ is that long double has to be able to represent all the values that a double can. Many compilers use 80 bits for long double, but Microsoft decided, about thirty years ago, that their stuff would be more portable if they used 64 bits. That's allowed by the standard. Regardless, the way to print a long double with C-style output functions is to use "%Lf" as the format specifier.

I think there is no way with current MSVC.

Side note: a plain (64-bit) single-precision double. This is an oxymoron. A double is... well a double-precision float, while float is single precision, according to IEEE.

long double is the same as double on msvc.

I can probably do it in assembly. All I need is to sprintf an 80-bit long double into a human-readable decimal. Although that is probably not as easy as it sounds
